# Projects dependencies between C# and C++ project, build order

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, dependencies

If both project `Alpha` and project `Beta` are C# projects, we can set that `Beta` depends on `Alpha` and this results to following build order: 1) `Alpha`; 2) `Beta`

If project `Alpha` is C++ project, we cannot add reference from project `Alpha` to `Beta` because Visual Studio 2010 does not allow this. Actually we can hack `csproj` file with notepad, but it doesn't help. Bu we can right click on solution, choose `Project Dependencies` and say that `Beta` depends on `Alpha`.

**Problem:** MSBuild does not honor dependencies set in `sln` file and builds projects in wrong order - 1) `Beta`; 2) `Alpha`. Note, that Visual Studio honors build order.

**How we can set build order for `MSBuild` between `C#` and `C++` projects within same solution?**

Answer (score 6):

Try adding your C++ project reference to the C# project **after** cleaning the solution. This works for me, although I stumbled on this "workaround" by pure chance.

To me it looks as if Visual Studio is checking the build product of the referenced project, and when it notices the incompatibility it will refuse to add the reference. If, however, the build product is not around to check (because you cleaned the solution), Visual Studio happily adds the reference.

I tested the resulting solution both in Visual Studio and on our TFS build server (which AFAIK uses `MSBuild`) and build dependencies were evaluated correctly in both cases.

In your question you also mention that manually editing the `.csproj` file didn't help. I cannot confirm this. I was able to add the following reference and again got a positive build result:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Foo\Foo.vcxproj">
  <Name>Foo</Name>
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
  <Private>False</Private>
</ProjectReference>
```

I am adding the `ReferenceOutputAssembly` element because [this blogs.msdn.com article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe.aspx) suggests it. In my experience, though, the build also works without the element. The article is still worth reading because it explains *why* `MSBuild` does not honor dependencies defined in the solution.

For completeness sake: I am running Visual Studio 2010, Version `10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel`.

Comment: Still applies: Using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 v11.0.60314.01 Update 2 - Workaround Works! -tnx